# Is there an equivalent to the DLP with extension fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

For instance, if I have an extension field of $p^n$, is there a way to recover $p$, other than brute force checking?

Comment: What does it mean to "have" such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. There is also a way to recover $p$ in fields of prime order other than brute force. All of [these algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) are faster than brute force. Yet, they are still not practical for real-world attacks.

So, if you meant for real world attacks, then then answer is yes, if the field has small characteristic. See for example [this paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/095) and [this list of papers](http://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/new-discrete-logarithm-records-and-the-death-of-type-1-pairings/).

For large characteristic fields, the answer is no (otherwise elliptic curve cryptography would be dead).

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'm still learning and I think this is one of those questions that shows I don't "know what I don't know" as it were.